# How to test OPTIONS request with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-headers, cors, capybara

What is a good way to test the OPTIONS response with Capybara?

Use case: need to configure Rails app response headers for CORS. I know this is not part of the "user experience". However, if the browser cannot make the request, the user is not going to be able to use the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to test the OPTIONS response with Capybara is by not using Capybara.

Jokes aside, this is better done in a <del>controller test</del> request spec since it does not involve any actual html parsing.

```
RSpec.describe 'Rabbits' do
  describe "GET /rabbits/:id" do
    it "enables CORS" do
      get rabbit_path(rabbit)
      expect(response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']).to eq "*"
    end
  end
end
```

You can test the OPTIONS http method with `process :show, "OPTIONS"` [[1]](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/925)

Comment: Basically you should not use Capybara since sending anything but a `GET` request (with `visit`) requires some pretty painful hacks which may or may not work depending on what driver is in use (such as rack_test, poltergeist or selenium). Capybara is also pretty slow since it is very high level and does a lot more than a controller test.

Comment: Note that sending POST or delete via forms or JS is a different case. I'm talking about sending a raw OPTIONS request from capybara.

Comment: I am getting `undefined method 'call' for` the app so it seems there is something wrong with the test setup...

Comment: Edited to reflect the fact that controller specs are now discouraged.